# Does fst supports (de)serialisation of objects not implementing Serializable interface?

Tags: java, serialization, java-11

Can someone let me know if [fst](https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization) supports serialization of classes not implementing the `Serializable` interface?

I have read [this](https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization/issues/22) discussion but it is not clear whether the library supports this? If yes then how to do it?

- fst - 2.57
- OpenJDK - 11